# Question about vector field on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, differential-equations

Arnold defined a vector field on a manifold M is a map from M to the tangent space of M (which has all derivations, roughly). In his ODE book, he talks about $\dot{x}(t) = v(x(t))$ for a vector field on a manifold.

$x(t)$ is a point on M, which depends on $t$. $v(x(t))$ is an element on tangent space, takes in an element of M and gives a number.

My question is what point of M is $v(x(t))$ taking?

Comment: V is the vectorfield, so the point is x(t).

Answer (score 1):

From the notation you use, my guess is that you are reading about the *flow* of the vector field.

If, in a local coordinate chart  $x^\mu$, $\mu=1,\ldots D$, we have the vector field
$$
V= V^\mu(x^1,x^2\ldots, x^D) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}
$$ 
 the flow $x^\mu(t)$ though a point $x_0^\mu$ is the solution to the system  of $D$ non-linear (in general) first-order differential  equations
$$
\frac{d x^\mu(t)}{dt}= V^\mu(x^1(t), x^2(t),\ldots, x^D), \quad \mu=1,\ldots, D
$$
with initial data $x^\mu(0)=x_0^\mu$. A shorthand for this system would be $\dot x=V(x(t))$ would it not? One can also consider the set of all solution curves though all possible starting points. The uniqueness theorem  for solutions of systems of first order ODE's will ensure that the curves  will not intersect  excepts at points where  $V\mu=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find it simplest to think of first a vector bundle. The main example of a vector bundle is the tangent bundle over a manifold.

Then a vector field is a section of vector bundle (in fact, they assemble into a sheaf). And we can then ask for it’s flow. It’s flow lines are integral curves of the vector field. It also turns out that local flows are equivalent to vector fields.